# TinyMCE - Button to wrap selection not selecting surrounding tags

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

In WordPress I have added a custom editor button to get the contents of a selection and wrap it in a shortcode. The content is not getting the tags surrounding the selection.

For example:

```
<h1>Heading text</h1>
```

becomes

```
<h1>[shortcode]Heading Text[/shortcode]</h1>
```

Not

```
[shortcode]<h1>Heading Text</h1>[/shortcode]
```

It does work for

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<h2>Sub-Header</h2>
```

becomes

```
[shortcode]<h1>Header</h1>
<h2>Sub-Header</h2>[/shortcode]
```

This is the code I have.

```
(function() {
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.zgwd', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
        ed.addButton('headerblock', {
            title : 'Add a Header Block',
            cmd: 'headerblock',
        });

        ed.addCommand('headerblock', function() {
            var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent({ format: 'html' });
            var return_text = '';
            if( !(selected_text && selected_text.length > 0) ) {
                selected_text = 'Add header block text here';
            }
            return_text = '[header-block]' + selected_text + '[/header-block]';
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, return_text);
        });

    },
    createControl : function(n, cm) {
        return null;
    },
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add('zgwd', tinymce.plugins.zgwd);
})();
```

How can I get the content including the `<h1>` tags (or similar). Am I using the wrong function to get the content or is there a setting I am missing somewhere? I tried `.getnode()` but get the same result.

Comment: Do you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with a single block tag, getNode is your best bet. If you look at this [Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xvgaab/14) with the console open in Dev Tools, try selecting one line, and then try selecting both. getNode() and getContent() behave a little differently based on selection.

getNode() Returns the selected element, but, if you have more than one element selected, it returns [the common ancestor](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#getnode) (in this case body).

getSelection() will return tags if you select multiple blocks, which is why it works when trying to surround more than one block tag.